# Having Twilio call 1 number, get the call status and then proceeding to call the next number on Apps Script

Tags: python, google-apps-script, twilio, google-sheets-api, twilio-api

I have a list of phone numbers to call on google spreadsheet and I have coded up on apps script to call the numbers.

However, I would like twilio to be able to call the first number, get its call status (completed, busy, failed etc), update it on the spreadsheet and then proceed to call the second number.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Qgs.png) is how I want my spreadsheet output to look like.

Currently, I am unable to get the call status from twilio using Apps Script. Would love to have some feedback on what I'm doing wrongly.

Thanks.

This is my Apps Script code

```
// Enter your Twilio account information here.
var TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = '';
var TWILIO_NUMBER = '';
var TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = '';

// Other variables
var STARTROW = 2
var STARTCOL = 1

// Creates the Call button on the menu bar
function onOpen() {
  // To learn about custom menus, please read:
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Call')
      .addItem('Call Selected', 'confirmCall')
      .addToUi();
};  

// Ensuring variables are entered
function checkSetup() {
  if (TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID && TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN) {
    return true;
  } else {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert('Please check your Twilio account details in AppScript');
    return false;
  }
}

// Confirmation Pop-up alert 
// Asks user if they have updated ngrok website
function confirmCall(){
  // Display a dialog box with a message and "Yes" and "No" buttons.
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('Is the Phone Number the last column and have you updated the ngrok website in the Apps Script?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  
  // Process the user's response.
  if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
    
    // Starts making the calls
    all_selected(); 
      
  } else {
    ui.alert('Please go to the Tools menu bar > Script Editor to update. \n If unsure, please check manual.');
    Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
  }
}  

// Intiates calls to the selected users 
function all_selected() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var totalRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - STARTROW + 1; 
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var nextColumn = numColumns + 1;

  // Create new column 
  sheet.getRange(1,nextColumn).setValue("Response")

  if (!checkSetup) {
    return 
  }

  if (numRows <= 0) {
    Logger.log("No one to call");
    var response = ui.alert('No calls to make');
    return;
  }

  for (var i = STARTROW; i <= (totalRows); i++) {
    var number = sheet.getRange(i,numColumns).getValue();
    var response = makeCall(number);

    //Browser.msgBox(response);
    // sheet.getRange(i,nextColumn + 1).setValue(response["status"])

    // If there is an error, update cell value to Nil
    if(response.code){
      sheet.getRange(i,nextColumn).setValue("Nil")
      Logger.log("Error has occured.");
    }

  }
}

// Calls a (ONE) person
function makeCall(to) {
  var call_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID + "/Calls.json";
  
  var payload = {
    "To": "+" + String(to),
    "From" : TWILIO_NUMBER,
    "Url": "http://821f72d16be7.ngrok.io/"   + "voice",
    "status_callback" : 'http://821f72d16be7.ngrok.io/' +  "status",
    "Method": "GET",
    "status_callback_event"  : ['queued', 'initiated'],
    "status_callback_method" : 'POST'
  };
  
  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };
  
  options.headers = {    
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(call_url, options);
  return JSON.parse(response);
}
```

This is my python Colab code

```
from flask import Flask, request, session
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

import os
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio import twiml
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Gather

from google.colab import auth

import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Change this if using a new sheet
sheet_id = ""

# Accesses the google spreadsheet 
auth.authenticate_user()
gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

# Opens the spreadsheet(****First sheet****)
worksheet = gc.open_by_key(sheet_id).sheet1

# Gets the number of columns in the current sheet
num_col = len(worksheet.get_all_values()[0])
col = num_col + 1

####################################################################
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = ''
TWILIO_NUMBER = ''
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = ''

client = Client(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)

# Makes connection using FLASK
app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)  

@app.route("/status", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def status():

    # Need to get the number of rows in that column 
    row = len(worksheet.col_values(num_col))

    worksheet.update_cell(row, col+1, request.values['Status'])
    # client = Client(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
    # record = client.calls.list(limit=1)
    # status = record.status

    
    # if status == 'failed':
    #   worksheet.update_cell(row, col, "failed")

@app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
    """Respond to incoming phone calls with a menu of options"""
    # Start our TwiML response
    resp = VoiceResponse()

    # Start our <Gather> verb
    gather = Gather(num_digits=1, action='/gather')
    gather.say('If you are interested in our service, press 1. If not, press 2.')
    resp.append(gather)

    # If the user doesn't select an option, redirect them into a loop
    resp.redirect('/voice')

    return str(resp)

@app.route('/gather', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gather():
    """Processes results from the <Gather> prompt in /voice"""
    # Start our TwiML response
    resp = VoiceResponse()

    # Need to get the number of rows in that column 
    row = len(worksheet.col_values(num_col))
    #row = rows_col + 1

    # If Twilio's request to our app included already gathered digits,
    # process them
    if 'Digits' in request.values:
        # Get which digit the caller chose
        choice = request.values['Digits']

        # <Say> a different message depending on the caller's choice
        if choice == '1':
            resp.say('You have indicated your interest. We will get back to you soon.')
            # Updating the cells (row, column, data)
            worksheet.update_cell(row, col, "Yes")
            return str(resp)

        elif choice == '2':
            resp.say('We understand your choice. Thank you.')
            # Updating the cells (row, column, data)
            worksheet.update_cell(row, col, "No")
            return str(resp)

        else:
            # If the caller didn't choose 1 or 2, apologize and ask them again
            # Updating the cells (row, column, data)
            ###### sheet.update_cell(row, num_col, "Nil")
            worksheet.update_cell(row, col, "Never indicate")
            resp.say("Sorry, I don't understand that choice. Please try again.")

    # If the user didn't choose 1 or 2 (or anything), send them back to /voice
    resp.redirect('/voice')
    
    return str(resp)

# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)

app.run()
```

Comment: Twilio has an open sourced project that has nearly identical requirements (without using Google Sheets) you can find here, Deliver voice notifications over the phone in just three steps - https://www.twilio.com/blog/voice-notification-app. Maybe you can glean some ideas from the repo - https://github.com/twilio/twilio-voice-notification-app.

Comment: You are getting the call status in your Python application. Can you update your Google Sheet from there, then call the next number?